# How to cite a reference to create a hyperlink from the citation call-out to the entry in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, citing

I have cited references in this way in my document:

- packages used: `cite` and `hyperref`
- citation in text: `\cite{1}`
- formatted entry in bibliography:

  ```
  \begin{thebibliography}{99}

  \bibitem{1}
  O. S. Bruning, P. Collier, P. Lebrun, S. Myers, R. Ostojic, J. Poole, 
  and P. Proudlock, LHC Design Report Vol. 1: The LHC Main Ring.
  ```

My question is that I can't click on citation call-out `[1]` in the text in a way that brings me to the corresponding entry in the bibliography.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\usepackage{cite}` is not necessary. You need to load `hyperref` in order to have links.

Comment: I used this package (  \usepackage{hyperref  } ) as well but still did not worked

Comment: \usepackage{cite} clobbers the links, whether loaded before or after hyperref.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. could you please suggest me how to solve this problem? Anything is still missing?

Answer (score 2):

The `natbib` citation management package offers excellent interoperability with the `hyperref` package. If you load `natbib`, be sure not to load the `cite` package.

Observe that since you're not employing BibTeX to create the formatted bibliography, there's no need to provide a `\bibliographystyle` directive.

Do try to provide more mnemonic keys than "1" for the bib entries.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % numeric citation call-out style
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\cite{bruning-et-mult}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{bruning-et-mult}
O. S. Bruning, P. Collier, P. Lebrun, S. Myers, R. Ostojic, J. Poole, 
and P. Proudlock, LHC Design Report Vol.1: The LHC Main Ring.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```